# how to send ajax via jquery in getcontenttools library

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

hi i'm using https://github.com/getmeuk/ContentTools library in my project, in the docs uses plain js to send ajax request, i want to send data using jquery,
but i have no idea how to that.

this is the code for sending ajax in plain javascript :

```
// Send the update content to the server to be saved
    onStateChange = function(ev) {
        // Check if the request is finished
        if (ev.target.readyState == 4) {
            editor.busy(false);
            if (ev.target.status == '200') {
                // Save was successful, notify the user with a flash
                if (!passive) {
                    new ContentTools.FlashUI('ok');
                }
            } else {
                // Save failed, notify the user with a flash
                new ContentTools.FlashUI('no');
            }
        }
    };

    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.addEventListener('readystatechange', onStateChange);
    xhr.open('POST', '/x/save-page');
    xhr.send(payload);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using JQuery this section of the tutorial could be rewritten like so:

```
// Collect the contents of each region into an object we can send to the 
// server.
var payload = {'__page__': window.location.pathname};
for (var name in regions) {
    payload[name] = regions[name];
}

// Send the updated content to the server to be saved
var req = $.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/x/save-page',
    data: payload
    });

req.done(function() {
    // Save was successful, notify the user with a flash
    new ContentTools.FlashUI('ok');
});

req.fail(function() {
    // Save failed, notify the user with a flash
    new ContentTools.FlashUI('no');
});

req.always(function() {
    // Make sure the editor is no longer set in a busy state
    ContentTools.EditorApp.get().busy(false);
});
```